# Stochastic Neighbor Embedding (SNE) - How to Understand the Cost Function of the Kullback Leibler (KL) Divergence

Tags: probability, optimization, machine-learning, divergence-operator

In the paper 'Stochastic Neighbor Embedding', the cost function in term of K-L divergence is

$$
  C
  = \sum_i \sum_j p_{ij} \log \frac{p_{ij}}{q_{ij}}
  = \sum_i \operatorname{KL}(P_i \| Q_i).
$$

**Question 1:**
Why does it say that SNE is an improvement over methods like LLE or SOM in which widely separated data-points can be 'collapsed' as near distances?

To minimize the cost, there is always a small distance in low-dimensional space with large $q_{ij}$, which also can cause 'collapse'. Or does 'collapse' mean something else?

**Question 2:**
Similarly, I do not understand how SNE keep the images of widely separated objects relatively far apart.

Comment: You should not use acronyms without writing them out at the first usage.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

The [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2276-stochastic-neighbor-embedding.pdf) discusses this in the following quote:

> Notice that making $q_{ij}$ large when $p_{ij}$ is small wastes some of the probability mass in the $q$
>   distribution so there is a cost for modeling a big distance in the high-dimensionalspace with
>   a small distance in the low-dimensional space, though it is less than the cost of modeling
>   a small distance with a big one. In this respect, SNE is an improvement over methods
>   like LLE [4] or SOM [5] in which widely separated data-points can be “collapsed” as near
>   neighbors in the low-dimensional space. The intuition is that while SNE emphasizes local
>   distances, its cost function cleanly enforces both keeping the images of nearby objects
>   nearby and keeping the images of widely separated objects relatively far apart.

Ideally, to minimize the KL, we should have $q_{ij} \approx p_{ij}$. Their point is that there is an asymmetry wrt increasing one compared to the other. Note that $p$ is inversely related to distance in the high-dimensional (HD) space, while $q$ is inversely related to distance in the low-dimensional (LD) embedding space. Large $q_{ij}$ with small $p_{ij}$ means modelling a large HD distance with a small LD distance. This penalty is born out in *other* terms of the sum, where $q_{k\ell}$ will be too small because some of the density of $q$ was "wasted" on $p_{ij}$. On the other hand, modelling a small HD distance with a large LD distance means having a large $p_{ij}$ with a small $q_{ij}$, meaning that $i,j$ will be a rather punishing term. I think what they mean is that without this asymmetry, this collapsing is more likely in LLE and SOM, perhaps.

**Question 2**

Basically re-iterating: to keep `the images of widely separated objects relatively far apart`, we want $q_{ij}$ to be small when $p_{ij}$ is small.

If the HD distance is far, then $p_{ij}$ will be small, (which makes it seem as if that term doesn't really matter as much since that it is $ p_{ij}\log(p_{ij}/q_{ij}) $). However, if the LD distance used there is small (meaning we didn't keep them far apart), then $q_{ij}$ will be large. Due to the normalization of $q$, this means we have "wasted" some of its probability mass here, and so other terms will be higher as a result. Hence the method will be driven to avoid this.